# The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect using @DateTimeFormat

Tags: java, mysql, json, spring, hibernate

I have a JSON formatted String which I send with a HTTP-PUT to a server with Spring MVC and Hibernate.

`Controller`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> myTest(
        @RequestHeader("a") String a,
        @RequestBody MyTestClass b) { … }
```

`JSON`:

```
{
 "number":"123",
 "test":"11/14"
}
```

`test` is a java.util.Date (MySQL -> date) and I annotated the POJO like this:

```
@Column(name = "TEST")
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM/yy")
private Date test;
```

So `test` should be formatted as month/year. But I tried it with Firefox RESTClient and I always get 
`The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.` Removing `test`, everything is okay and works as expected.

So it seems, that with `@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM/yy")` is something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are using `RequestBody` with an `application/json` content type, Spring will use its `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` to convert your JSON to an object of your type. However the date string you provide, `11/14` does not match any of the pre-configured date patterns and therefore it can't parse it correctly. The `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`, or more specifically the `ObjectMapper` that does the job, doesn't know anything about `@DateTimeFormat`, a Spring annotation.

You will need to tell Jackson which date pattern you want to use. You can do so with a custom date deserializer

```
public class CustomDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Date> {
    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yy");
        String date = jp.getText();

        try {
            return format.parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new JsonParseException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Then simply annotate your field so that Jackson knows how to deserialize it.

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDateDeserializer.class)
private Date test;
```

You could use `@DateTimeFormat` if you were using url-encoded form parameters with `@ModelAttribute`. Spring registers some converters that can convert a String value from a request parameters into a `Date` object. [This is described in the deocumentation.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#format)