# Spring DateTimeFormat.ISO.Date preconfigured pattern returns syntactically incorrect

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to pass a date in my URL in the format: 2014/12/12

So my **url** looks like:

```
http://192.0.0.1/api/getdata?date=2014-12-12
```

My **controller method** looks like:

```
 public Iterable<Object> getObject(
        @RequestParam(value = "date", required = false) 
        @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) Date date)
```

I am getting the tomcat **error**

```
       <b>description</b>
            <u>The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.</u>
```

I thought if I was using a pre-configured date pattern, there would no be an issue with parsing the date?

[The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect using @DateTimeFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897254/the-request-sent-by-the-client-was-syntactically-incorrect-using-datetimeformat)

I have looked at the question above which is similar. But the question is using MM/yy which isn't preconfigured. Do I still need a custom date deserializer anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format yyyy/MM/dd is a bad format to be passing the date, for the reason Sambhunath mentioned. However if you have to use this format, you should register your binder

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    dateFormat.setLenient(false);
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));
}
```

and remove the  `@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)` annotation, from the argument.

Another thing is that from your question is not clear if you want to use the `yyyy-MM-dd` format, in which case your code is fine, and the issue your having is the error in your request. Remove the `&` from

```
http://192.0.0.1/api/getdata?&date=2014-12-12
```

so make it

```
http://192.0.0.1/api/getdata?date=2014-12-12
```

Comment: opps you are correct, I took out another parameter I had to make the code clearer. I've edited the question to remove the &. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Spring supports rest URL, so your the date format you want to pass will be divided into 3 parts.
It will not be possible to send the date in url using this format.You need to change the date format which you want to pass.